# vgaswitcheroo has no effect

Tags: kernel, graphics, ati, intel-graphics, vgaswitcheroo

I have a Dual Graphics setup on my Laptop.

```
[root@MISTRI ashesh] $ lspci -vnn | grep '\''[030[02]\]'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] [1002:6840] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
```

What I am trying to do is reduce heat by turning off the ATI card but `vgaswitcheroo` doesn't seem to be working.

**Before:**

```
[ashesh@MISTRI ~] $ su -c "cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch"
Password: 
0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
1:DIS: :DynOff:0000:01:00.0
```

**Then:**

```
[ashesh@MISTRI ~] $ su -c "echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch"
```

**After:**

```
[ashesh@MISTRI ~] $ su -c "cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch"
Password: 
0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
1:DIS: :DynOff:0000:01:00.0
```

**No change at all. The dynamic power management by the kernel is not doing enough and I have got to turn it off. Any suggestions?**

PS: There is no option in BIOS as well.

---

EDIT 1:

```
[ashesh@MISTRI ~] $ lspci -knn | grep Radeon -A2
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] [1002:6840] (rev ff)
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Radeon -A2` terminal command.

Comment: done, as I mentioned in my question description, right now the kernel is responsible for managing the card.

Answer (score 1):

Install the proprietary driver by

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
```

and reboot.

Then switch the adapters using Catalyst GUI or

```
sudo aticonfig --px-dgpu
```

to AMD

```
sudo aticonfig --px-igpu
```

to Intel.